# Set default folder view in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-vista

In Windows Vista, whenever I open a folder, the selection of columns is nonsensical: album, date taken, etc., for folders that contain no music or pictures whatsoever. I can select the correct columns for a particular folder, but all the other folders are still wrong, even when I go in to Folder Options and click the button to set the current options to all folders of this type.

How can I tell Windows to use the current column selection for all folders, unless otherwise specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eZine Article: [Setup a Default Folder View in Windows Vista](http://ezinearticles.com/?Solved---Setup-a-Default-Folder-View-in-Windows-Vista!&id=1465143)  talks about some registry stuff along with the points in `Daniel`'s answer.  Below is from this link

> One of the problems many people face once they have installed Vista is
>   that their folder view will change every time they close and reopen a
>   folder. This is annoying right?
>
> Well here is the solution:
>
> 1 Open the registry: Simply click on the start orb and type in "regedit" into the search field. A file called regedit.exe will show
>   up at the top, double-click it!
>
> 2 Locate the following folders in the registry editor by clicking on the small black arrows to expand the folder structure:
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareClassesLocal
>   SettingsSoftwareMicrosoftWindowsShellBags]
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareClassesLocal
>   SettingsSoftwareMicrosoftWindowsShellBagMRU]
>
> 3 Right click on the folder "Bags" and click on delete, do the same for BagMRU. This is how you get rid of disturbing folder view entries.
>   Don't worry we will now create a new one called "DefaultFolders".
>
> 4 Right click on the folder "Shell" that is the parent folder of the folders you just deleted.
>
> Click on "New" -> "Key". Name it "DefaultFolders".
>
> 5 Repeat 4. but for the folder we just created and name the new folder "Shell". That way you will create a subfolder "Shell" inside
>   the folder "DefaultFolders".
>
> 6 Now we right-click on the folder "Shell" and create a new String: "New" -> "String Value".
>
> Give the string the name "FolderType".
>
> 7 Double-click it and type "Documents" into the value field.
>
> 8 Almost done, now all folders will have the same folder view as the "Documents" folder. Time to set your default folder view. To do that
>   open up the explorer (Windows-key + E is the shortcut).
>
> Now locate C:UsersYour_User_NameDocuments, where C: is the partition
>   on which you installed Windows obviously. Make sure to set your
>   favorite folder view (mine is Details) there.
>
> Click on "Organize" -> "Folder and Search Options".
>
> Now go to the tab "View" and finally click on "Apply to Folders"!

I have used the steps from `Daniel`'s answer on Windows XP machines.
If they do not work on the Vista, try the eZine article.

Meanwhile, this Vista64 thread suggests Vista SP2 has solved this problem.

Answer (score 4):

First you set the columns the way you want in one folder, then on the Tools menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> if the menu is hidden by default), click Folder Options... and then go to the View tab, click Apply to Folders. After confirming, you will see that all your folders (at least of that type) have been changed.

PS. Thanks for asking; it reminded me that I needed to set this up.

Comment: This will work for some time and then foul up. You need to combine this with my answer for it to "stick".

Answer (score 0):

See this article from annoyances.org : ["Default Folder Template Patch"](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/choosetemplate), which says:

> Windows Vista has a bug that prevents
>   it from choosing the correct view for
>   a folder based on its contents, which
>   is why you may see thumbnails when
>   they're not appropriate, and no
>   thumbnails when they're needed. The
>   following patch stops Vista from
>   trying to guess how to display a
>   folder, instead forcing it to use the
>   template of your choice.